# AWS Cognito doesn't work in release mode, exception: "The type initializer for AmazonCognitoIdentityProviderConfig"

Tags: amazon-web-services, xamarin

It's the first time that I use AWS services, I read a lot of things, but I can't find my answer about my issue nothing works. I use Xamarin, and all my nuggets are updated.

I have an issue that's happened only when I'm in release mode. 
I try to sign up a user, in debug mode, it works I created a user, I saw it in user pool, and I interact with dynamoDB.
In release i have this exception :

*"The type initializer for 'Amazon.CognitoIdentity.AmazonCognitoIdentityProviderConfig' threw an exception."*

My App.config :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="aws" type="Amazon.AWSSection, AWSSDK.Core"/>
  </configSections>
  <aws region="us-west-2" profileName="xxxxx">
  </aws>
  <appSettings>
      <!-- AWS Cognito Identity Settings -->
      <add key="AWSProfileName" value="xxx"/>
      <add key="AWSRegion" value="eu-west-2"/>
      <add key="CLIENT_ID" value="xxxx" />
      <add key="USERPOOL_ID" value="eu-west-xxxx" />
      <add key="IDENTITYPOOL_ID" value="eu-west-2:x-x-x-x-xx" />
      <add key="IDENTITY_PROVIDER" value="cognito-idp.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/" />
       <add key="ID_KEY" value="xxxx" />
        <add key="SECRET_KEY" value="xxxx" />
         <add key="AWS.S3.UseSignatureVersion4" value="true"/>
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

My code :

```
SignUpRequest signUpRequest = new SignUpRequest()
{
    ClientId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["CLIENT_ID"],
    Password = SubscribePagePassword.Text,
    Username = editUsername.Text
};

AttributeType emailAttribute = new AttributeType()
{
    Name = "email",
    Value = editadressemail.Text
};

AttributeType birthdateAttribute = new AttributeType()
{
    Name = "birthdate",
    Value = SubscribePageBirthday.Text
};

signUpRequest.UserAttributes.Add(emailAttribute);
signUpRequest.UserAttributes.Add(birthdateAttribute);

AnonymousAWSCredentials credentials = new AnonymousAWSCredentials();
var ConnectCognito = new AmazonCognitoIdentityProviderClient(credentials, RegionEndpoint.EUWest2);
var signUpResult = await ConnectCognito.SignUpAsync(signUpRequest);
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Nobody has a beginning of answer ?